# Why are my values for sum and count being lost each loop?

Tags: c

I'm getting a consistent divide by zero error, even though each loop should be populating the variables. Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void calculateAverage()
{
int grade, count, sum;
double average;


sum = 0;
count = 0;
grade = 0;
average = 0.0;
int coolvalue = 0;

while (coolvalue==0)
{
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    if (grade == -1)
    {
        sum, sizeof(double);
        count, sizeof(double);
        average = (sum / count);
        printf("%lf", &average);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((grade > 100) || (grade < -1))
        {
            printf("Error, incorrect input.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = +grade;
            count = count + 1;
            return count;
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
coolvalue = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
while (1)
calculateAverage();

while (1) getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Even while using return, I'm not able to properly increment the value of sum or count.

Comment: `sum, sizeof(double);`, `sum = +grade;`, etc: much weirdness.  What the heck are you trying to accomplish here???

Comment: You are prematurely returning from the function in the `else` condition.

Comment: @paulsm4 the type cast is in order to not have a type mismatch when calculating the average, the sum is increased by grade each time that part of the code is reached. I'm trying to create a program that continually asks for grades adds those grades to sum and increases count by one each time a new grade runs through, then is terminated when -1 is input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how so? the else condition is only returned from prematurely if an incorrect value is an input, otherwise, there is no other way to leave the loop besides letting it run out.

Comment: `sum, sizeof(double)` is an expression that does not have any effect. The compiler does not even generate code for it.

Comment: The same holds true for `count, sizeof(double);` ??  Time for a talk with the rubber-duck, see [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) -- really, it helps...

Comment: Do you successfully scan for grade? Is the returnvalue of `scanf()` as expected? I.e. does it indicate 1 successfully scanned variable?

Comment: `void calculateAverage()` does not allow to return any value. You do return a value here `return count;` and futily attempt to return a second value here `return sum;`. Where do you expect those values to go? Are you aware that you only can return one value (even if the function head DOES allow it?

Comment: May also be very helpful to separate your *input* routines from your `calculateAverage` function. Handle your input either in `main()` or in a separate function and pass an array of values and the number of values as parameters to `calculateAverage`. That allows separate validation of your input before attempting to manipulate the values. Short functions that do a single-job help keep your logic and error handling straight.

Comment: You intend this `coolvalue = 1;` to end the loop. Then when do you expect it to be executed? It seems to be outside of the loop.

Comment: @ChrisSchmierer - understand that none of these are dings to you, but a collection of advise and suggestions as well as a dissection of your posted code to help you understand how to approach coding (beyond which functions do what -- you can get that from the man-pages). The read gems are understanding the thought-process of "How do I approach a project that I haven't done, of feel uncomfortable doing. As with all, start with the basics, compile with *warnings enabled*, and do not accept code until it compiles without warning (you will learn as much from your compiler as you will from a book

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues in your code.

`scanf("%d", &grade);` - you don't check the value returned by `scanf()`. It returns the number of values successfully read. If you enter a string of letters instead of a number, `scanf("%d")` returns `0` and it does not change the value of `grade`. Because of this the code will execute the rest of the loop using the previous value of `grade`. You should restart the loop if the value returned by `scanf()` is not `1`:

```
if (scanf("%d", &grade) != 1) {
    continue;
}
```

Assuming you enter `10` for `grade` this block of code executes:

```
sum = +grade;
count = count + 1;
return count;
return sum;
```

- `sum = +grade` is the same as `sum = grade`. The `+` sign in front of `grade` doesn't have any effect. It is just the same as `0 + grade`.

  You want to add the value of `grade` to `sum` and it should be `sum += grade`. This is a shortcut of `sum = sum + grade`.
- `return count` makes the function complete and return the value of `count` (which is `1` at this point) to the caller. The caller is the function `main()` but it doesn't use the return value in any way. Even more, your function is declared as returning `void` (i.e. nothing) and this renders `return count` incorrect (and the compiler should warn you about this).
- `return sum` is never executed (the compiler should warn you about it being dead code) because the function completes and the execution is passed back to the caller because of the `return count` statement above it.

  Remove both `return` statements. They must not stay here.

If you enter `-1` for `grade`, this block of code is executed:

```
sum, sizeof(double);
count, sizeof(double);
average = (sum / count);
printf("%lf", &average);
break;
```

- `sum, sizeof(double)` is an expression that does not have any effect; it takes the value of `sum` then discards it then takes the value of `sizeof(double)` (which is a constant) and discards it too. The compiler does not even generate code for it.
- the same as above for `count, sizeof(double)`;
- `average = (sum / count);`:

  - the parenthesis are useless;
  - because both `sum` and `count` are integers, `sum / count` is also an integer (the integral result of `sum / count`, the remainder is ignored).

    you declared `average` as `double`; to get a `double` result you have to cast one of the values to `double` on the division: `average = (double)sum / count;`
  - if you enter `-1` as the first value when the program starts, `count` is `0` when this code is executed and the division fails (division by zero).
- `printf("%lf", &average);` - you want to print the value of `average` but you print its address in memory. Remove the `&` operator; it is required by `scanf()` (to know where to put the read values). It is not required by `printf()`; the compiler generates code that passes to `printf()` the values to print.
- `break;` - it passes the execution control after the innermost `switch` or loop statement (`do`, `while` or `for`). It is correct here and makes the variable `coolvalue` useless. You can simply remove `coolvalue` and use `while (1)` instead.

All in all, your function should look like:

```
void calculateAverage()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int grade = 0;
    double average = 0.0;

    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &grade) != 1) {
            // Invalid value (not a number); ignore it
            continue;
        }

        // A value of -1 signals the end of the input
        if (grade == -1) {
            if (count > 0) {
                // Show the average
                average = (double)sum / count;
                printf("Average: %lf\n", average);
            } else {
                // Cannot compute the average
                puts("You didn't enter any value. Cannot compute the average.\n");
            }
            // End function
            return;
        }

        if ((grade < -1) || (100 < grade)) {
            puts("Error, incorrect input.\n");
            // Invalid input, ignore it
            continue;
        }

        sum += grade;
        count ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that about covers it, aside from not checking the return of `scanf`, so there is little assurance of processing valid data before the remainder of issues are hit.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few corrections need to be made.

1. The `while` loop in the `calculateAverage()` function. That's an infinite loop buddy, because you are not changing the value of that `coolValue` variable anywhere inside, instead you make it `1` only when it exits the loops, which it never will. 
   So, use `while(1) {...}`, and inside it, check for the stopping condition, i.e, `if (grade == -1) { ... }` and inside it calculate and print the `average` and `return`. This will automatically break the `while`.
2. You're not checking if the input `grade` is actually a valid integer or not. Check the value of `scanf` for that, i.e, use `if (scanf("%d", &grade) != 1) { ... }`
3. The expression `sum = +grade;` is just another way of writing `sum = 0+grade` which in turn is nothing but `sum = grade`. Replace this with `sum += grade;`. This is the right way to write a shorthand for addition.
4. Two `return` statements..a very wrong idea. First of all, a function can have just one `return`(in an obvious way I mean, at once). Secondly, the function `calculateAverage()` is of return-type `void`. there's no way how you can return `double` value from it. So remove these two statements.

I have attached the code below which works. Also do go through the output which I have attached.

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateAverage()
{
    int grade, count = 0, sum = 0;
    double average;
    printf("\nenter the grades... enter -1 to terminate the entries\n.");
    while (1) {
        printf("\nEnter the grade: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &grade) != 1) {
            printf("\nInvalid characters entered!!!");
            continue;
        }
        else if(((grade > 100) || (grade < -1))) {
            printf("\nInvalid grade entered!!!");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            if (grade == -1) {
                average = sum/count;
                printf("\nAverage value of grades: %.3lf",average);
                return;
            }
            else {
                sum += grade;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  calculateAverage();
  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> enter the grades... enter -1 to terminate the entries.
>
> Enter the grade:  50
>
> Enter the grade:  100
>
> Enter the grade:  60
>
> Enter the grade:  -1
>
> Average value of grades: 70.000

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is better for the function to be of type double instead of void. Although it is not my favorite solution it is close to what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
double  calculateAverage(void)
    {
        double average;
        int sum = 0, count=0, grade;
        while (1)
        {           
            scanf("%d", &grade);    
            if ((grade > 100) || (grade < -1))              
                printf("Error, incorrect input.\n");    
            else if (grade != -1)
                {sum = sum+ grade;  count = count + 1;}             
            else
                break;              
        }
        if (count==0) 
            average=-1.0; //none valid input. Notify the main()
        else    
            average=(double)sum/count;
        return average;  
     }

int main(void)
    {
        double result;
        result= calculateAverage();
        if (result!=-1.0)
            printf("\n average= %lf",result);
        else    
            printf("No grades to calculate average");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```